# Sort a list of chained tuples with sortWith

Tags: list, scala, sorting, higher-order-functions

given a list of Tuple2's, I want to sort them so that the second element of one of them is the first element of the next. I have tried doing it with sortWith but it's working in some cases but not in others. Can anyone spot where I'm messing up?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3-20130923-e2fec6b28dfd73482945ffab85d9b582d0cb9f17 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_71).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val l = List((2,3),(1,2),(3,4))
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (1,2), (3,4))

scala> l.sortWith((x,y) => x._2 == y._1)
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4))

scala> val m = List((2,3),(5,6),(1,2),(3,4),(4,5))
m: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4), (4,5))

scala> m.sortWith((x,y) => x._2 == y._1)
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4), (4,5))
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Sorted doesn't work. For instance, it sorts (3,2), (2,1) backwards.

Comment: Hmm, the comment to which I commented was deleted so now it looks like my comment was directed to OP. For the record there was a comment about using "sorted" instead of "sortWith"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sortWith basically says that if the condition is true then the first arg should come somewhere before the second arg and if the condition is false then they should be ordered the other way.  For the vast majority of comparisons your sortWith condition is returning false, which is pushing things to the right even after a previous comparison has said something should go more left.

In short, your sortWith isn't consistent and you're getting inconsistent results.

Before you can come up with a generalized solution you have to deal with some deep issues with the problem space. What you are basically trying to do is sort an arbitrary directed graph. That means it can have cycles, disconnected subgraphs, and all sorts of other things that preclude any obvious total ordering.

But if we can assume you avoid cycles then a topological sort might give you something more like the results you are looking for. Basically the property you need is isn't just "put this one before that one if the this one's right point is equal to that one's left point" but something more like "put this one before that one if [all that] otherwise we don't have enough information to compare them." sortWith isn't sophisticated enough to do a topological sort. It assumes all elements can be compared directly meaningfully.

A quick intro to topological sorting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `Comparator` which is used for `sortWith` you'll find:

```
def sortWith(lt: (A, A) => Boolean): Repr = sorted(Ordering fromLessThan lt)

def fromLessThan[T](cmp: (T, T) => Boolean): Ordering[T] = new Ordering[T] {
    def compare(x: T, y: T) = if (cmp(x, y)) -1 else if (cmp(y, x)) 1 else 0
```

so for instance with your `x._2 == y._1` when underlying algorithm compares `(5,6)` and `(1,2)` it will check first that `6` not equals to `1` then that `2` not equals to `5` and finally will decide that these tuples are equal. For that reason you should use something like this:

```
x._2 <= y._1 // for tuples where _1 < _2
x._2 >= y._1 // for tuples where _1 > _2
```

Comment: This is still not right. Imagine at some point you're comparing (1,2), (3,4). Which should come first? Answer: no idea at all. The next pair could be (2,3) in which case you need one ordering or it could be (4,1) in which case you need another.

Comment: For `(1,2), (3,4)` because `2 <= 3` `(1,2)` will come first. Provided solution expects that all tuples wil be `_1 < _2` or `_1 > _2`, so there will be no case for `(1,2)` or `(3,4)` and `(4,1)`.